# How launcher accessing Icon pack?

Tags: android, android-launcher, android-icons

There are lots of icon pack avails on Google play store, which are compatible with launchers, I just wonder that how launcher access & identify such icon pack so it get reflect to launchers.

I succeed to code inside `Icon pack` which linked to launcher but `ow launcher accessing such icon pack, so it will handle appropriate icon pack and get reflect to launcher?`

*code within icon pack, define necessary launcher package name@*

```
            <!-- Go / Nova -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="com.gau.go.launcherex.theme" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- LauncherPro / Holo -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="com.fede.launcher.THEME_ICONPACK" />
            </intent-filter>
```

I follwed [XDA developers Guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1649891) but not get any solution, can anyone shed the light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This application has all the intent filters for different launchers and there will an action according to that intent. these are defined by the launchers `<action android:name="com.gau.go.launcherex.theme" />`
 and `<category android:name="com.fede.launcher.THEME_ICONPACK" />` and your application take actions according to these and provide icons when specific launcher fires an intent.

Comment: Only `action & category` do the magic or have to do any thing extra? have you any tutorial or any other well document?

Comment: Ya, that should be all.
you can use these links
http://code.google.com/p/adw-launcher-android/wiki/ADWThemeGuide#Getting_Started_On_Your_ADW.Launcher_Theme

https://github.com/AnderWeb/ADW.Theme-Template

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2399426